# Using a for loop to condense code

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have the following code which I would like to condense into a for loop but not sure how. I tried looking at other posts but got stuck.

There are 15 numbers all together so something like for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++)

```
       if(checksquare1save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare1").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare1").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare2save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare2").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare2").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare3save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare3").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare3").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare4save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare4").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare4").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare5save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare5").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare5").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare6save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare6").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare6").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare7save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare7").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare7").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare8save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare8").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare8").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare9save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare9").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare9").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare10save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare10").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare10").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare11save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare11").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare11").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare12save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare12").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare12").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare13save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare13").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare13").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }


        if(checksquare14save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare14").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare14").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }

        if(checksquare15save=="true"){
            $("#checksquare15").toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }

        else{
            $("#checksquare15").removeClass("checksquareON");
        }
```

I did try this but it didn't work

```
        for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
            if(checksquare + i + save=="true"){
                $("#checksquare" + i).toggleClass("checksquareON");
            }   
        }
```

Edit:

Should have mentioned I have these vars above

```
        checksquare1save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check1-7868-2171-1085-5119-4672'] 
        checksquare2save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check2-6582-7209-6435-8487-6994']
        checksquare3save =  localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check3-5367-9000-3502-5810-2295']
        checksquare4save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check4-2961-8359-5106-2702-5132'] 
        checksquare5save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check5-5801-5256-5838-2934-5277'] 
        checksquare6save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check6-1162-2208-7274-5156-3693']
        checksquare7save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check7-6178-4335-3148-1809-8066']
        checksquare8save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check8-6609-6032-4539-4243-6273']
        checksquare9save =  localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check9-6261-3580-7658-7073-1914']
        checksquare10save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check10-1504-7246-1864-4465-1319']
        checksquare11save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check11-6400-3954-7124-3585-2086']
        checksquare12save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check12-8303-8392-7301-5154-8007']
        checksquare13save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check13-1207-8834-5941-3315-8893']
        checksquare14save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check14-3089-4036-1427-2614-7399']
        checksquare15save = localStorage['ScienceSkills-basicSkillsCheck-check15-2750-4976-5357-6403-2979']
```

Comment: `if(checksquare + i + save=="true"){` i think the wrong is here

Comment: set checksquareXsave variable as array. Easier to get its value because you can just do checksquaresave[i]

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work if your variables are in the global scope:

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
        if(window['checksquare' + i + 'save']=="true"){
            $("#checksquare" + i).toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }
        else{
            $("#checksquare" + i).removeClass("checksquareON");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edited my original post with the arrays I used if that helps

Comment: The `.` between the window and the bracket is causing a syntax error. Remove it and it'll be fine. :)

Comment: Still does not really tell me if it's in the global scope, but I think it should work.

Comment: Agrrr! Typo... Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

you better use an array `checksquaresave` and push into it all your `checksquareXsave` then loop the array like you're doing. it requires a bit of refactoring, but it'll save you some pain later on.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
   if(checksquare[i] == 'true'){
       $("#checksquare" + i).toggleClass("checksquareON");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the code you are doing right now will check the value of 3 variables:
checksquare, i & save, instead of one.

a beter way would be to put all your data in an array and go through this.

if you had an array: checksquaresave. then you could fill it up with your values:

```
checksquaresave[0] =value0, checksquaresave[1] =value1 , ...
```

after this the code would be as simple as:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
    if(checksquaresave[i] =="true"){
        $("#checksquare" + i).toggleClass("checksquareON");
    }   
}
```

---

**EDIT:** as @Archer mentioned (and other answers as well) you can use

```
window["checksquare" + i + "save"]
```

as well, but I think the best way would be to just use an array. (cfr. [using window["variable" + i] in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684384/using-windowvariable-i-in-javascript))

Comment: Yes you can... `window["checksquare" + i + "save"]`, but I agree that an array would be better ;)

Comment: Ah didn't know that! This will probably not be best practice though? (performance wise)

Comment: I'd say it's not best practice, without giving a reason.  It's just an unpleasant way of coding, and the very reason we have arrays!  But, still handy to know.

Answer (score 1):

When *only* shown the code that you have, the only solution that I can think of involves the use of `eval`. Forget I said that though, because you don't want to attempt that solution. Having 15 similarly-named variables is likely an issue. You might be able to use `window.variableName` or `window["variableName"]` to retrieve them IF the "checksquaresave" variables are globals. In that case, it would look like:

```
if (window["checksquare" + i + "save"] == "true")
```

Otherwise, it would be good to inspect the creation of the checksquare##save variables, and set them up as an array rather than seperate variables. Then, your code could look like this:

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
        if(checksquaresave[i] =="true"){
            $("#checksquare" + i).toggleClass("checksquareON");
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access variables for which you know the name only at runtime, you can store them as properties of an object.

So if you want to access checksquare1save, checksquare2save, etc, you can do this:

```
var storage = {
    checksquare0save:true,
    checksquare1save:true,
    checksquare2save:false,
    //...other variables...
}

for (var i = 0; i < 15, i++) {
    console.log(storage["checksquare" + i + "save"])
}
```