# using window["variable" + i] in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

In a recent question ([Using a for loop to condense code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683627/using-a-for-loop-to-condense-code/)) on stack overflow, I've learned that you can loop through variable names via the window object.

After reading this I was wondering if this is considered bad habbit and if this affects performance in certain ways.

I would guess that this does lower the performance of you Javascript since you are creating a lot more variables than when you are using an array for example. but if you are accessing a variable via it's direct name "variable" vs. "window[variable]", does this have a certain impact as well? Is this a different approach for retreiving the value? Or are these 2 possibilities doing exactly the same thing?

---

**EDIT:** 
As @Tomalak said, it's probably useless to ask for performance problems, since I'm not experiencing them.

Since it is a bad habbit to put a lot of variable names in the window object, what would be a use case where you would use window[variable] instead of an alternative? Is there a usecase for this?

Comment: A first best practice would be not to put variables in the window (global) scope...

Comment: Whatever the performance implications are here, it's plain and simple bad practice, because variable variables are virtually always bad practice! For dynamic lists of an unknown number of items you use *arrays*, that's what they're there for.

Comment: This doesn't answer the performance question but in the linked example I would create a single array `checkSquare` and then refer to its members as e.g. `checkSquare[7]`. Then `checkSquare` can be enumerated implicitly

Comment: That was something that didn't feel right for me as well, but I was just wondering if this has any consequences (except for just being "bad code")

Comment: Don't ask performance questions *unless* you have actual, specific performance problems. You don't need to optimize for problems you don't have and you should not waste your time thinking into this direction. Whether it's a good thing to put many variables into the window object and what alternatives exist that's the real question here.

Comment: It is, as others had said, bad practice. However, for performance questions, check out [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) and you can answer these questions yourself.

Comment: You'd be talking *nanoseconds* of computing performance here, although not using loops would dramatically increase the number of seconds it takes for a developer to read it.

Comment: @Tomalak you're probably right. I guess the best alternative is just arrays ...

Comment: @Kristof Definitely. If you have something you want to "loop over", arrays are the way to go.

Comment: If you really want to use this pattern, use your own object instead of `window` so you don't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: I've added a question ... Is there any case you would use this window[variable] instead of an alternative? because I can't seem to find any case where this can come in handy (except for using variables inside the name, but then again this is bad practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to use global variables. It's also considered bad practice to have dynamic variable names, which is what you would be doing when using this technique. To store lists of items, use an array. That's what arrays are there for.

Now, as for computing time... the difference is on a scale of fractions of *fractions* of seconds. However, using `window["variable" + i] is slower` because in order to look up the appropriate value, the property string needs to be concatenated. With an array, you just pass in the index, and nothing needs to be concatenated or converted to a string, which is what happens with object lookups. So avoiding `window["variable" + i]` is actually minutely faster.

As for cases when using dynamic variables is actually useful--well, there aren't many. The only possible use for `window[variableName]` that I can think of is if `variableName` refers to a function you need to call. That would look like this: `window["someFunction"]();`.

**tl;dr**: Don't do this, as it affects performance negatively (albeit negligibly) and is bad practice on several levels. The only time it's "okay" is when you're calling a function by name--but be careful there, too, as doing that is pretty much equivalent to using `eval`, which is, of course, evil.

Answer (score 1):

`window` object is already full of variables and despite tons of smartheads in internet trying to dictate the universally best coding style, it is still mostly matter of personal preference. One has to do what one has to do. In short, @Tomalak nailed it with his comment - there's no need to over-engineer it. Simplicity is most often the best way.

One way to keep it tidy is to declare your own object to `window` (`window.myGlobals` and put all the stuff you need into that one.

Answer (score 0):

Placing your variables in global scope (as property of the window object in the case of browsers) is called namespace pollution and it is a bad form because it makes understanding the code much more difficult compared to nicely separated, modular code. Difficult to understand code leads to bugs and difficulties in maintenance.

There are reasons why you would place some variables in the global space (because they are needed by more than one script), but it's usually common practice to place as few as possible. For example the jQuery library places the `jQuery` object in the global scope. Anything else is self contained or exposed as properties of that object. jQuery plugins make use of that object and also offer an interface through it.

In your particular case, you had a bunch of information extracted from localStorage and placed into numbered variables. The solution with window['id' + i] is offered as a patch that alters little of your code, but it would be best if you encapsulated all the data in an array which you can access simply as data[i]. Note that this array is also in the global scope, but it is the only one in the global scope.